# Check if the jms queue is up

Tags: spring, jms, apache-camel

Is there a way catch that time-out and send it back to user?
Not sure if Apache Camel provides something out of the box.

I want to test and alert the user which queues are up and running. So that it will be clear to user that which functionality of the application will work or not.
I am using both `Spring` and `Apache Camel` in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I found out. Camel has an out of the box solution.

```
Camel 2.1: Specifies whether to test the connection on startup. This ensures that when Camel starts that all the JMS consumers have a valid connection to the JMS broker. If a connection cannot be granted then Camel throws an exception on startup. This ensures that Camel is not started with failed connections. From Camel 2.8 onwards also the JMS producers is tested as well.
```